# PostgreSQL joining multiple tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

Hi guys I am trying to join tables here, I want to add table called Table2 so that students from that table are displayed too. The thing which is confusing is I already have joins in this query, so how should add another join so that  students from that Table2 are displayed as well, without breaking the existing code . Also, there is no way I can check output

The ID varables are stsidno in stTable 1, sidno in Table2, scsidno in table schedprd

Here's the code:

```
                String selS = "select distinct stdistrict,stschool,stsidno,"
                  + " sname as name,stgrade,"
                  + "S.recnum as recnum, S.stldate as stldate,scsec,sctea,sccor,scgrade,scclsprd,scgrdprd,"
                  + "case when P.scchangestartdate is null then C.clstart else "
                  + "P.scchangestartdate end as scchangestartdate, "
                  + "case when S.stedate is null or S.stedate<C.clstart "
                  + "then C.clstart else S.stedate end as stedate "
                  + "from stTable1 as S join schedprd as P on "
                  + "(scyear=styear and scdistrict=stdistrict and scschool=stschool "
                  + "and stsidno=scsidno and (scsec is not null and scsec<>'')) "
                  + "left outer join calendar as C on (C.clyear=S.styear and "
                  + "C.cldistrict=S.stdistrict and C.clschool=S.stschool and C.cltype='10') "
                  + "where styear=? and stdistrict=? ";
```

Comment: Are the students in table 1 and table 2 different students? Is the structure of tables 1 and 2 the same?

Comment: structure is same table1 contains variables such as stdistrict, stschool, the ones starting with st

Comment: Unless we know your data structure and relations between tables it's hard to tell which joins may be causing duplicating records. This leads to being unable to rewrite the query to be efficient.

Answer (score 0):

You could `UNION` Table1 and Table2 together in a `Common Table Expression (CTE)` and then reference the CTE instead of Table1 in your query, like below:

```
WITH CTE
AS
(
SELECT *
FROM Table1
UNION
SELECT *
FROM Table2
)

select distinct 
stdistrict,
stschool,
stsidno,
sname as name,
stgrade,
S.recnum as recnum, 
S.stldate as stldate,
scsec,
sctea,
sccor,
scgrade,
scclsprd,
scgrdprd,
case when P.scchangestartdate is null then C.clstart else P.scchangestartdate end as scchangestartdate,
case when S.stedate is null or S.stedate<C.clstart then C.clstart else S.stedate end as stedate
from CTE as S 
join schedprd as P on (scyear=styear and scdistrict=stdistrict and scschool=stschool and stsidno=scsidno and (scsec is not null and scsec<>'')) 
left outer join calendar as C on (C.clyear=S.styear and C.cldistrict=S.stdistrict and C.clschool=S.stschool and C.cltype='10')
where styear=? and stdistrict=?;
```

Comment: Wont it slow down the execution? as its already executing select stdistrict, stschool, stsidno and other stuff from table1

Comment: Run it and see! Worry about actuals, not maybes